# PHP beginner. Trying to display UserId

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am accessing my database on PhpMyAdmin, all my names etc are correct, but for some reason **UserId** is not working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried printing it but nothing displays.

```
<?php session_start(); 
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];


// Create connection


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user2 where username='$username' and   password='$password'");

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_cnt >0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$UserId = $row['UserId'];
}
$sqlQuery2 = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Price, Description FROM product";

echo "Hello ".$username."<br>" .$UserId.   "<br> This is a list of products";

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQuery2);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ProductID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>View</th>
 </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['ProductID'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td><a href=\"detailview.php?ProductID=".$row['ProductID']."\"'>Detailed View</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<a href="userupdatedetails.php?UserId=<?php echo $UserId ?>">Update My Details</a>
<?php } else{
echo "invalid login "; }
?>
```

Comment: Is `UserId` a column in your database?

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` to see what yoe really have in that variable

Comment: You really need to read up on sql injection and safe password storage through hashing.

Comment: Please, for all that is holy. Drop all your knowledge of mysqli and start reading all about PDO. For example: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Are you storing plain password, without any kind of encryption? Or did you just forget to hash what is in `$_GET['password']`.
By the way, try var_dumping $row_cnt and $row and see what you get

Comment: Very silly..tis actually UserID. Thank you for var_dump($row)

Answer (score 0):

use var_dump($var) to see what is in the variable

1st check what is returned in $result and after check $UserId before using it
after the while check if $UserId is set (if the condition is false, ou var is not set..)  you should check $row_count too

you should indent your code
here is your code reindented :

```
<?php session_start(); 
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];


// Create connection


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user2 where username='$username' and   password='$password'");

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_cnt >0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $UserId = $row['UserId'];
    }
    $sqlQuery2 = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Price, Description FROM product";

    echo "Hello ".$username."<br>" .$UserId.   "<br> This is a list of products";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQuery2);

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ProductID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>View</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ProductID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"detailview.php?ProductID=".$row['ProductID']."\"'>Detailed View</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    <a href="userupdatedetails.php?UserId=<?php echo $UserId ?>">Update My Details</a>
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "invalid login ";
}
?>
```

Comment: it's closed at the end    <?php }
    else {
        echo "invalid login ";
    }
    ?>

Comment: ah ok, sorry the program didn't indented the code correctly and has 1 tab much (maybe because there was no return)...  you see good indentation is essential while coding....  what about var dumps?

i edited the post and gave the corect version of your indented code